# Highcharts 3D Scatter Plot, pop up's and links after rotation

Tags: highcharts

I am working on a multi-series 3D Scatter Plot based on the demo here.

https://www.highcharts.com/demo/3d-scatter-draggable

Each point has a pop up when hovered over and mine links to a unique URL when the point is clicked, these both work very well until the 3D chart is rotated, after rotation neither the popup or the link will work, this is evident in the demo linked above.

Is this a limitation of the 3D scatter? or can it be remedied?

Thanks

Comment: I think it is a regression bug. It worked in 5.0.10 version, stopped in 5.0.11 http://jsfiddle.net/w66oh37k/ Bug reported here https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/6703

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @morganfree for the solution.

Downgrade to version 5.0.10 with the following

```
<script src="//code.highcharts.com/5.0.10/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="//code.highcharts.com/5.0.10/highcharts-3d.js"></script>

<script src="//code.highcharts.com/5.0.10/modules/exporting.js"></script>
```

tested and working :)